# VPS, Java, connection timeout and out of memory

Tags: java, linux, talend

I'm running a JAR  (for instance, a [Talend](http://www.talend.com/) job) from a virtual linux machine (VPS).

I'm facing on a **Connection timed out** exception when I'm running the jar.

I can't fully explain it because if I run the JAR inside Eclipse (inside Talend ESB Studio, for instance) it works correctly. The jar is doing some HTTP GET calls, and measuring them with chrome dev tool they are from 10s up to 40s.

While investigating why this exception is thrown I've found in the jar directory a file called **hs_err_pid6127.log** with some log about  **insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue**.

Here is my question: can the two things can be linked somehow? How can I know the actual memory for Java Run Time Enviroment? Can it be the cause of the timeout? If yes, how can it be resolved?

The JAR exception stacktrace:

```
Exception in component tREST_2
com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out
        at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler.handle(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:131)
        at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.handle(Client.java:616)
        at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:559)
        at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.get(WebResource.java:182)
        at jobtest.forwardjson_0_1.ForwardJSON.tREST_2Process(ForwardJSON.java:1770)
        at jobtest.forwardjson_0_1.ForwardJSON.tFileInputRaw_2Process(ForwardJSON.java:1257)
        at jobtest.forwardjson_0_1.ForwardJSON.tFileInputRaw_1Process(ForwardJSON.java:984)
        at jobtest.forwardjson_0_1.ForwardJSON.tJava_2Process(ForwardJSON.java:713)
        at jobtest.forwardjson_0_1.ForwardJSON.runJobInTOS(ForwardJSON.java:3400)
        at jobtest.forwardjson_0_1.ForwardJSON.main(ForwardJSON.java:3127)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
        at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:211)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:308)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:326)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:997)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:933)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:851)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1301)
        at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:468)
        at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler._invoke(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:218)
        at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler.handle(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:129)
        ... 9 more
```

Content of the log file with insufficient memory error:

```
#
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Native memory allocation (malloc) failed to allocate 179306496 bytes for committing reserved memory.
# Possible reasons:
#   The system is out of physical RAM or swap space
#   In 32 bit mode, the process size limit was hit
# Possible solutions:
#   Reduce memory load on the system
#   Increase physical memory or swap space
#   Check if swap backing store is full
#   Use 64 bit Java on a 64 bit OS
#   Decrease Java heap size (-Xmx/-Xms)
#   Decrease number of Java threads
#   Decrease Java thread stack sizes (-Xss)
#   Set larger code cache with -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=
# This output file may be truncated or incomplete.
#
#  Out of Memory Error (os_linux.cpp:2756), pid=6127, tid=122490359273216
#
# JRE version:  (7.0_80-b15) (build )
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (24.80-b11 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x00006f677c00a000):  JavaThread "Unknown thread" [_thread_in_vm, id=6128, stack(0x00006f67824a5000,0x00006f67825a6000)]

Stack: [0x00006f67824a5000,0x00006f67825a6000],  sp=0x00006f67825a4270,  free space=1020k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
V  [libjvm.so+0x9a320a]  VMError::report_and_die()+0x2ea
V  [libjvm.so+0x498d3b]  report_vm_out_of_memory(char const*, int, unsigned long, char const*)+0x9b
V  [libjvm.so+0x82191e]  os::Linux::commit_memory_impl(char*, unsigned long, bool)+0xfe
V  [libjvm.so+0x821e69]  os::pd_commit_memory(char*, unsigned long, unsigned long, bool)+0x29
V  [libjvm.so+0x81bb6a]  os::commit_memory(char*, unsigned long, unsigned long, bool)+0x2a
V  [libjvm.so+0x88d623]  PSVirtualSpace::expand_by(unsigned long)+0x53
V  [libjvm.so+0x87c293]  PSOldGen::initialize(ReservedSpace, unsigned long, char const*, int)+0x103
V  [libjvm.so+0x29ace3]  AdjoiningGenerations::AdjoiningGenerations(ReservedSpace, unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned long)+0x3e3
V  [libjvm.so+0x843215]  ParallelScavengeHeap::initialize()+0x4d5
V  [libjvm.so+0x97509a]  Universe::initialize_heap()+0xca
V  [libjvm.so+0x976269]  universe_init()+0x79
V  [libjvm.so+0x5b2f25]  init_globals()+0x65
V  [libjvm.so+0x95db4d]  Threads::create_vm(JavaVMInitArgs*, bool*)+0x1ed
V  [libjvm.so+0x63b2e4]  JNI_CreateJavaVM+0x74
C  [libjli.so+0x2f8e]  JavaMain+0x9e


---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )

Other Threads:

=>0x00006f677c00a000 (exited) JavaThread "Unknown thread" [_thread_in_vm, id=6128, stack(0x00006f67824a5000,0x00006f67825a6000)]

VM state:not at safepoint (not fully initialized)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

GC Heap History (0 events):
No events

Deoptimization events (0 events):
No events

Internal exceptions (0 events):
No events

Events (0 events):
No events


Dynamic libraries:
00400000-00401000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 661565                             /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/java
00600000-00601000 rw-p 00000000 08:01 661565                             /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/java
00601000-023d6000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
023d6000-023f8000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
6f67330d6000-6f6733254000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
6f6733254000-6f673327f000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
6f673327f000-6f67332ff000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
6f67332ff000-6f6733300000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
6f6733300000-6f6733380000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
6f6733380000-6f6738580000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
6f6742f13000-6f6743080000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
6f6743080000-6f6763000000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
6f6763000000-6f6768580000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
6f6768580000-6f6778580000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
6f6768580000-6f6778580000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
6f6778598000-6f6778808000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0
6f6778808000-6f677b598000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
6f677b598000-6f677b5af000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 661261                     /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/libzip.so
6f677b5af000-6f677b7af000 ---p 00017000 08:01 661261                     /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/libzip.so
6f677b7af000-6f677b7b0000 rw-p 00017000 08:01 661261                     /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/libzip.so
6f677b7b0000-6f677b7bc000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 786478                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.21.so
6f677b7bc000-6f677b9bb000 ---p 0000c000 08:01 786478                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.21.so
6f677b9bb000-6f677b9bc000 r--p 0000b000 08:01 786478                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.21.so
6f677b9bc000-6f677b9bd000 rw-p 0000c000 08:01 786478                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.21.so
6f677b9c0000-6f677b9cb000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 786465                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_nis-2.21.so
6f677b9cb000-6f677bbca000 ---p 0000b000 08:01 786465                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_nis-2.21.so
6f677bbca000-6f677bbcb000 r--p 0000a000 08:01 786465                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_nis-2.21.so
6f677bbcb000-6f677bbcc000 rw-p 0000b000 08:01 786465                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_nis-2.21.so
6f677bbd0000-6f677bbe7000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 786484                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnsl-2.21.so
6f677bbe7000-6f677bde6000 ---p 00017000 08:01 786484                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnsl-2.21.so
6f677bde6000-6f677bde7000 r--p 00016000 08:01 786484                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnsl-2.21.so
6f677bde7000-6f677bde8000 rw-p 00017000 08:01 786484                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnsl-2.21.so
6f677bde8000-6f677bdea000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
6f677bdf0000-6f677bdf8000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 786480                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_compat-2.21.so
6f677bdf8000-6f677bff7000 ---p 00008000 08:01 786480                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_compat-2.21.so
6f677bff7000-6f677bff8000 r--p 00007000 08:01 786480                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_compat-2.21.so
6f677bff8000-6f677bff9000 rw-p 00008000 08:01 786480                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_compat-2.21.so
6f677c000000-6f677c026000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
6f677c026000-6f6780000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
6f67800fc000-6f67801d8000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
6f67801d8000-6f6780201000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 661227                     /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/libjava.so
6f6780201000-6f6780401000 ---p 00029000 08:01 661227                     /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/libjava.so
6f6780401000-6f6780403000 rw-p 00029000 08:01 661227                     /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/libjava.so
6f6780408000-6f6780415000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 661254                     /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/libverify.so
6f6780415000-6f6780614000 ---p 0000d000 08:01 661254                     /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/libverify.so
6f6780614000-6f6780616000 rw-p 0000c000 08:01 661254                     /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/libverify.so
6f6780618000-6f678061f000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 786497                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt-2.21.so
6f678061f000-6f678081e000 ---p 00007000 08:01 786497                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt-2.21.so
6f678081e000-6f678081f000 r--p 00006000 08:01 786497                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt-2.21.so
6f678081f000-6f6780820000 rw-p 00007000 08:01 786497                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt-2.21.so
6f6780820000-6f6780927000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 786483                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.21.so
6f6780927000-6f6780b26000 ---p 00107000 08:01 786483                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.21.so
6f6780b26000-6f6780b27000 r--p 00106000 08:01 786483                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.21.so
6f6780b27000-6f6780b28000 rw-p 00107000 08:01 786483                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.21.so
6f6780b28000-6f678169e000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 661281                     /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
6f678169e000-6f678189d000 ---p 00b76000 08:01 661281                     /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
6f678189d000-6f6781961000 rw-p 00b75000 08:01 661281                     /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
6f6781961000-6f67819a2000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
6f6781961000-6f67819a2000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
6f67819a8000-6f6781b68000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 786503                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.21.so
6f6781b68000-6f6781d68000 ---p 001c0000 08:01 786503                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.21.so
6f6781d68000-6f6781d6c000 r--p 001c0000 08:01 786503                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.21.so
6f6781d6c000-6f6781d6e000 rw-p 001c4000 08:01 786503                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.21.so
6f6781d6e000-6f6781d72000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
6f6781d78000-6f6781d7b000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 786471                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.21.so
6f6781d7b000-6f6781f7a000 ---p 00003000 08:01 786471                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.21.so
6f6781f7a000-6f6781f7b000 r--p 00002000 08:01 786471                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.21.so
6f6781f7b000-6f6781f7c000 rw-p 00003000 08:01 786471                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.21.so
6f6781f80000-6f6781f95000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 661273                     /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/jli/libjli.so
6f6781f95000-6f6782194000 ---p 00015000 08:01 661273                     /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/jli/libjli.so
6f6782194000-6f6782195000 rw-p 00014000 08:01 661273                     /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/jli/libjli.so
6f6782198000-6f67821b0000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 786475                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.21.so
6f67821b0000-6f67823b0000 ---p 00018000 08:01 786475                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.21.so
6f67823b0000-6f67823b1000 r--p 00018000 08:01 786475                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.21.so
6f67823b1000-6f67823b2000 rw-p 00019000 08:01 786475                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.21.so
6f67823b2000-6f67823b6000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
6f67823b8000-6f67823dc000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 786474                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.21.so
6f67823e5000-6f67823ef000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
6f67823ef000-6f67824a5000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
6f67824a5000-6f67824a8000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
6f67824a8000-6f67825a6000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack:6128]
6f67825c0000-6f67825c8000 rw-s 00000000 08:01 1311123                    /tmp/hsperfdata_root/6127
6f67825ce000-6f67825d0000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
6f67825d4000-6f67825d7000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
6f67825d7000-6f67825d8000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0
6f67825d8000-6f67825db000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
6f67825db000-6f67825dc000 r--p 00023000 08:01 786474                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.21.so
6f67825dc000-6f67825dd000 rw-p 00024000 08:01 786474                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.21.so
6f67825dd000-6f67825df000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
6f67825df000-6f67825e1000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
715d736a8000-715d736ca000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]

VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -Xms256M -Xmx1024M
java_command: talendjobtest.forwardjson_0_1.ForwardJSON --context=Default
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

Environment Variables:
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
SHELL=/bin/sh

Signal Handlers:
SIGSEGV: [libjvm.so+0x9a3b20], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGBUS: [libjvm.so+0x9a3b20], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGFPE: [libjvm.so+0x81e740], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGPIPE: [libjvm.so+0x81e740], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGXFSZ: [libjvm.so+0x81e740], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGILL: [libjvm.so+0x81e740], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGUSR1: SIG_DFL, sa_mask[0]=0x00000000, sa_flags=0x00000000
SIGUSR2: [libjvm.so+0x81ffb0], sa_mask[0]=0x00000000, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGHUP: SIG_DFL, sa_mask[0]=0x00000000, sa_flags=0x00000000
SIGINT: SIG_DFL, sa_mask[0]=0x00000000, sa_flags=0x00000000
SIGTERM: SIG_DFL, sa_mask[0]=0x00000000, sa_flags=0x00000000
SIGQUIT: SIG_DFL, sa_mask[0]=0x00000000, sa_flags=0x00000000


---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS:jessie/sid

uname:Linux 3.14.32-xxxx-grs-ipv6-64-vps #1 SMP Sat Feb 7 11:39:32 CET 2015 x86_64
libc:glibc 2.21 NPTL 2.21
rlimit: STACK 8192k, CORE 0k, NPROC 7963, NOFILE 65536, AS infinity
load average:0.13 0.04 0.05

/proc/meminfo:
MemTotal:        2039816 kB
MemFree:           84776 kB
MemAvailable:     150456 kB
Buffers:           31448 kB
Cached:            45968 kB
SwapCached:         8360 kB
Active:          1345272 kB
Inactive:         463056 kB
Active(anon):    1296372 kB
Inactive(anon):   438476 kB
Active(file):      48900 kB
Inactive(file):    24580 kB
Unevictable:           0 kB
Mlocked:               0 kB
SwapTotal:       2099196 kB
SwapFree:           9020 kB
Dirty:               384 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:       1722672 kB
Mapped:            23088 kB
Shmem:              3916 kB
Slab:              38616 kB
SReclaimable:      12896 kB
SUnreclaim:        25720 kB
KernelStack:       11776 kB
PageTables:        28396 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:     3119104 kB
Committed_AS:   14661200 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:      289572 kB
VmallocChunk:   34359346732 kB
HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
DirectMap4k:       10176 kB
DirectMap2M:     2086912 kB
DirectMap1G:           0 kB


CPU:total 2 (1 cores per cpu, 1 threads per core) family 21 model 0 stepping 2, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2, popcnt, avx, aes, mmxext, 3dnowpref, lzcnt, sse4a, tsc, tscinvbit, tscinv

/proc/cpuinfo:
processor       : 0
vendor_id       : AuthenticAMD
cpu family      : 21
model           : 0
model name      : AMD Opteron(tm) Processor 6386 SE
stepping        : 2
microcode       : 0x6000822
cpu MHz         : 2799.999
cache size      : 2048 KB
physical id     : 0
siblings        : 1
core id         : 0
cpu cores       : 1
apicid          : 0
initial apicid  : 0
fpu             : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 40 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor       : 1
vendor_id       : AuthenticAMD
cpu family      : 21
model           : 0
model name      : AMD Opteron(tm) Processor 6386 SE
stepping        : 2
microcode       : 0x6000822
cpu MHz         : 2799.999
cache size      : 2048 KB
physical id     : 2
siblings        : 1
core id         : 0
cpu cores       : 1
apicid          : 2
initial apicid  : 2
fpu             : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level     : 13
wp              : yes
flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 syscall nx mmxext fxsr_opt pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc rep_good nopl tsc_reliable nonstop_tsc aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq ssse3 cx16 sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic popcnt aes xsave avx hypervisor lahf_lm extapic cr8_legacy abm sse4a misalignsse 3dnowprefetch osvw xop fma4 arat vmmcall
bogomips        : 5599.99
TLB size        : 1536 4K pages
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 40 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:



Memory: 4k page, physical 2039816k(84776k free), swap 2099196k(9020k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (24.80-b11) for linux-amd64 JRE (1.7.0_80-b15), built on Apr 10 2015 19:53:14 by "java_re" with gcc 4.3.0 20080428 (Red Hat 4.3.0-8)

time: Fri Aug 21 12:55:01 2015
elapsed time: 0 seconds
```

Linux version:

```
# uname -a
Linux vps177513.ovh.net 3.14.32-xxxx-grs-ipv6-64-vps #1 SMP Sat Feb 7 11:39:32 CET 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

EDIT -- Some more interesting fact:

```
# free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          1992       1898         93          4         36         42
-/+ buffers/cache:       1819        172
Swap:         2049       2046          3
```

And to respond to a comment I run the JAR via this script:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd `dirname $0`
 ROOT_PATH=`pwd`
 java -Xms256M -Xmx1024M -cp $ROOT_PATH:$ROOT_PATH/../lib/systemRoutines.jar:$ROOT_PATH/../lib/userRoutines.jar::.:$ROOT_PATH/forwardjson_0_1.ja r:$ROOT_PATH/../lib/camel-core-2.13.2.jar:$ROOT_PATH/../lib/commons-io-2.4.jar:$ROOT_PATH/../lib/cxf-api-2.7.12.jar:$ROOT_PATH/../lib/cxf-rt-bin dings-xml-2.7.12.jar:$ROOT_PATH/../lib/cxf-rt-core-2.7.12.jar:$ROOT_PATH/../lib/cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs-2.7.12.jar:$ROOT_PATH/../lib/cxf-rt-rs-ext ension-providers-2.7.12.jar:$ROOT_PATH/../lib/cxf-rt-transports-http-2.7.12.jar:$ROOT_PATH/../lib/dom4j-1.6.1.jar:$ROOT_PATH/../lib/javax.ws.rs- api-2.0-m10.jar:$ROOT_PATH/../lib/jersey-client-1.4.jar:$ROOT_PATH/../lib/jersey-core-1.4.jar:$ROOT_PATH/../lib/jettison-1.3.5.jar:$ROOT_PATH/.. /lib/log4j-1.2.15.jar:$ROOT_PATH/../lib/mail.jar:$ROOT_PATH/../lib/slf4j-api-1.7.7.jar:$ROOT_PATH/../lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.7.jar:$ROOT_PATH/../l ib/stax-api-1.0.1.jar:$ROOT_PATH/../lib/stax2-api-3.1.4.jar:$ROOT_PATH/../lib/woodstox-core-asl-4.4.0.jar:$ROOT_PATH/../lib/wsdl4j-1.6.3.jar:$RO OT_PATH/../lib/xmlschema-core-2.1.0.jar: talendjobtest.forwardjson_0_1.ForwardJSON --context=Default "$@" root@vps177513:~/talend/ForwardJSON #
```

Comment: Well obviously the JVM tried to allocate 179306496 bytes and failed. What size is your VPS? And how do you start that jar? If via a script, you may find -Xmx and/or -Xms parameters that may help diagnose the issue. But my first idea is that probably your VPS is a bit on the small side.

Comment: @fvu: see the edits. Which command to understand the VPS size?

Comment: the top command (and especially the M view) can help you understand where the memory of the VM is being used - as you can derive from the output of free, the total memory is 1992MB, so it's a 2GB VM.

Comment: I suspect the issue with jar. It looks like resources (like iostreams) are not getting closed.

Answer (score 1):

You need a profiler to see what is consuming memory over time. I don't see how a stateless web service would continue to chew up memory unless you had a leak somewhere.  Could be perm gen; could be something else.  Measure; don't guess.

A 32 bit JVM won't allow you allocate more than [2GB](http://theserverside.com/news/thread.tss?thread_id=26347) heap size.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Did you see the edit with the free command? Do you have some profiler to advice?

Comment: The Windows JVM ships with VisualVM.exe.  I don't know about Linux.  I would recommend that first, because it's free.  dynaTrace or JProfiler would be my commercial recommendations.